# Duplicate append in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have one simple table (containing user data) look like this:

```
<div class="col-md-offset-1" id="userList" style="height:550px; width:80%; overflow:auto; margin-top:30px;">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="userTable">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">
                ID
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">
                Name
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center"> Operation </th>
        </tr>

        <tbody>
            @RenderPage("_DataGridView.cshtml")
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My PartionView ("_DataGridView.cshtml") look like this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Model.FindingList[i].ID
        </td>
        <td>
            @Model.FindingList[i].Name
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return ViewInfo('@Model.FindingList[i].ID', '@Model.FindingList[i].Name')"> Detail </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return EditInfo('@Model.FindingList[i].ID', '@Model.FindingList[i].Name')"> Edit </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

And my Javascript file look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var currentPageNumber = 1;
    var search = $('#s_name').val();

    var userTable = $('#userTable tbody');

    $('#userList').on('scroll', function () {
        if (Math.round($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight(), 10) >= Math.round($(this)[0].scrollHeight, 10)) {
            currentPageNumber++;
            loadData(currentPageNumber);
        }
    })

    function loadData(currentPage) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:62888/Training/Search',
            method: 'post',
            data: { name: search, pageNumber: currentPage, pageSize: 10 },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

                data = jQuery.unique(data);

                $(data).each(function (index, user) {

                    userTable.append('<tr>' +
                        '<td>' + user.ID + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + user.Name + '</td>' +
                        '<td scope="col" class="text-center">' +
                              '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return ViewInfo(\'' + user.ID + '\', \'' + user.Name + '\')">Detail</button>' +
                              '&nbsp &nbsp' +
                              '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return EditInfo(\'' + user.ID + '\', \'' + user.Name + '\')">Edit</button>' +
                        '</td>' +
                     '</tr>')
                })

            }
        });
    }
});
```

The site will automatically detect when the scroll is scrolled to end with the code:

```
$('#userList').on('scroll', function () {
                if (Math.round($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight(), 10) >= Math.round($(this)[0].scrollHeight, 10)) {
                    currentPageNumber++;
                    loadData(currentPageNumber);
                }
            })
```

When scrolling down to the end. it will load the data by calling the ajax in loadData() function.

All data will automatically return into pieces. Each piece contains 10 records in table. Here is the one of the pieces returns from the server:

> "[{\"ID\":\"19\",\"Name\":\"Barrack
>   Obama\"},{\"ID\":\"2\",\"Name\":\"Nguyen Van
>   Bao\"},{\"ID\":\"20\",\"Name\":\"Abraham
>   Lincoln\"},{\"ID\":\"21\",\"Name\":\"Thomas
>   Edinson\"},{\"ID\":\"22\",\"Name\":\"Donald
>   Trump\"},{\"ID\":\"23\",\"Name\":\"Oda
>   Nobunaga\"},{\"ID\":\"24\",\"Name\":\"Julius
>   Ceasar\"},{\"ID\":\"25\",\"Name\":\"George
>   Washington\"},{\"ID\":\"3\",\"Name\":\"Tran Thi
>   Cuc\"},{\"ID\":\"4\",\"Name\":\"Pham Huynh E\"}]"

My problem is when i **scroll down to the end of the bar**, it **appends duplicately** the ajax returning results. So it turns into two part of data in the view page (all data in database is copied twice). My question is:

> How it happens and how i can fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Please share the call that is being send when you scroll down and the result from the server

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal the ajax calling is in loadData() function and $('#userList').on('scroll', function () {...} check when user scroll down to end.

Comment: Please check on the ajax call - Is the same call being send twice or the data received from server is the same across 2 calls?

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal It is just called once in the $('#userList').on('scroll', function () {...}

Comment: I am not talking about the event that sends call, but the call itself. Check in your network and see which calls are being send. Do you see a duplicate call there?

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal I have debugged 10 times and don't see any calls are being called twice.